# How to prevent iframe of navigating and catch 404 error message?

Tags: javascript, iframe

In my webpage there is an iframe, inside that iframe there are lot of clickable items, when one of then is clicked the iframe crash with error 404 and return in console something like:

```
tavoli.aspx?IH=A:60 GET http://12.12.12.12/Web/1 404 (Not Found)
```

How could i prevent the iframe to redirect to that page so the iframe will be still alive and how could i catch the `http://12.12.12.12/Web/1`?

Comment: Is the iframe cross origin? If so, does it send the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header? If the iframe is cross origin, and does not have the header, things get rather complex and failure prone.